# Uneven group size in 2 way anova

Tags: anova

For 2 x 2 between-subjects design: I have 227 responses to a 4 condition group questionnaire online. I used a G*Power 3.1 calculator assuming power 0.90 and alpha level 0.05 and to detect medium effects (f = .25) and determined that I need a sample of 206. One group has only 201, the rest have more. Does this mean I only have a sample size of 204 as I require even groups for that statistical power or can I have uneven groups and have the same statistical significance?